# How to get the data from fixed month in a year and from fixed month data should be mandatory

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i have one year data in my table now i want the data from every month of october. For suppose if i ran a query in this month i will get the data oflast 12 months data and including october.
but if i ran same query next month i will get the data of last 12 months and i will not get october data.
here is the query i have written:

```
SELECT distinct Y_column 
FROM X table
WHERE Y_column  >= DATEADD(MONTH, -14, GETDATE())
```

this is the output i am getting

```
2015-10-01 00:00:00.000
2015-11-02 00:00:00.000
2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
2016-01-01 00:00:00.000
2016-02-01 00:00:00.000
2016-03-01 00:00:00.000
2016-04-01 00:00:00.000
2016-05-02 00:00:00.000
2016-06-01 00:00:00.000
2016-07-01 00:00:00.000
2016-08-01 00:00:00.000
2016-09-01 00:00:00.000
2016-10-03 00:00:00.000
2016-11-01 00:00:00.000
```

could you please help me how can i get the data from every october in the year if i run the same query in next month.

Comment: Kindly tag only one DBMS and remove which are irrelevant.

Comment: some example and sample data..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MSSQL; If you just wanted the data for October onwards in the current year

```
SELECT distinct Y_column 
FROM X table
WHERE Y_column >= CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-10-01' AS DATETIME)
```

If you want to show from the last October:

```
SELECT distinct Y_column 
FROM X table
WHERE Y_column >= CAST(CAST(CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) < 10 THEN YEAR(GETDATE())-1 ELSE YEAR(GETDATE()) END AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-10-01' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: but it will give only october month date i need the data from october to till date.

Comment: If you want to get data from a particular date onwards you would just use a filter like this WHERE Y_column >= '2015-10-01' OR if you only want up until today:  WHERE Y_column BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND GETDATE()

Comment: i don't want hard-code any date .with out hard-code i need the data starts from october to till date.

Comment: Hi Chris,Thanks,Now i want to get the last two years data also including the data will start from october. could you please help me on this?For Suppose the query which you are provided giving this year october and november data.but, i need the data of 2015 and 2014 and the data should start from october.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what you are asking for..? Can you supply an example of the expected output in your question?

Comment: Hi Chris,above i mentioned my expected output where u altered the query.

Comment: Hi Chris,Thank You so much .Finally i got my expected output.:)